# How to procedurally select random parts of a texture and mask out the rest

Tags: shaders

I want to be able to programmatically select random parts of a `Texture` and mask out the rest. To rephrase it another way - I want blender to randomly select parts of the texture and keep it - all else gets discarded.

How would I accomplish this?

**`Image: Wave Texture with random areas highlighted`**

[image]

My goal is to create something similar to this: https://www.artblocks.io/project/282

[image]

Comment: Really programmatically (by python) or do you mean procedurally?

Comment: yep procedurally - ill update the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am not sure, but do you want something like this? Here i masked out the brick texture with a noise texture:

[image]

[image]

and this is how you can replace it with another texture:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This was sort of what I was looking for - but I was more looking for something which would 'track' along the noise of, for instance, the wave texture

Comment: What do you mean with track? I don’t understand? Maybe you can show a picture of your mask and how it should look as result?

Comment: ah sorry its quite difficult to articulate. Ive been thinking over it in my head and the only way to do what I want to would be with machine learning and computer vision. Simply speaking, the algorithm would look for *clumps* of black in the image. Once it has recognised clumps in the image, it would randomly select, then discard some of the clumps. I apologise in advance if that doesn't make sense - but don't worry because its not something that blender can accomplish.

Comment: Don’t worry. I know how hard is something visually to explain just with words…